# error connection refused

Tags: android

I want to make an Http Connection to my own servlet. Here is my code:

```
try
{
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpMethod = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8080/getHeader/HeaderServlet");
    httppost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
    ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
    String response = client.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
    String result = response.toString();
}
```

But i'm unable to, and I get the error:

```
org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectionException:Connection to http://localhost:8080 refused
```

I will be thankful your help

Comment: If you're still facing the issue, feel free to give this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67032554/12298875) a try

Answer (score 148):

### Use `10.0.2.2` instead of `localhost`.

If you are referring to a `localhost` from your device than use the `http://10.0.2.2/` instead of the `http://127.0.0.1/` or `http://localhost/`.

Because your Android emulator is running on a `Virtual Machine(QEMU)` and you can not connect to a server directly running on your PC.

So your code snippet will be like this:

```
HttpPost httpMethod = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2:8080/getHeader/HeaderServlet");
```

Refer this : [Emulator Networking](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking) for more information.

Comment: @Vikas I tried using `10.0.2.2`, but does not work for me. I have `INTERNET` permission added in manifest file.

Comment: For those who are looking for more suggestions to avoid `Connection refused`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20015883/connecting-localhost-via-android-connection-to-10-0-2-2-refused/22313837#22313837

Answer (score 23):

I had the same problem but I solved it by putting in the following label said

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

which allowed me to connect to the Internet.

Answer (score 8):

The better is that you put your PC LAN's IP , for example , in windows , run "ipconfig" in a cmd console , suppose that your IP is : 192.168.1.34 , 
then

```
HttpPost httpMethod = 
   new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.34:8080/getHeader/HeaderServlet");
```

Comment: 10.0.0.2 did not work for me, looking up my IP and using that solved this problem for me.

Comment: @DJ_Polly, The IP is 10.0.2.2. Did you try that?

Answer (score 3):

`localhost` would be the Android device itself. I assume that this is not where your servlet is. You'll need to enter the hostname or IP of wherever your servlet is.

(If it's really on your device (why?!), then you need to make sure you have the INTERNET permission. You could try connecting to it from the built-in browser.)

Comment: the servlet is on my own Pc and yes i had already set the internet Permissions in Android Manifest

Comment: Well, your own PC is not your Android device, even if you're using an emulator.

Answer (score 0):

For me problem solved by deleting proxyHost,proxyPort, etc from gradle.properties