# android: Force Closes

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I'm new with android application development and I'm trying to develop a working application. But this page I created is giving problem since it has been created and i really hope someone can help me with this. Each time I run this program, the application force closes.

This is the source code:

```
public class Latest extends ListActivity {

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// Creating JSON Parser object
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> eventsList;

// url to get all products list
private static String url_all_products = "http://";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_BOOKS = "books";
private static final String TAG_TITLE = "title";
private static final String TAG_AUTHOR = "author";
private static final String TAG_DESCRIPTION = "description";
private static final String TAG_PRICE = "price";
private static final String TAG_DISCOUNT = "discount";
private static final String TAG_CATEGORY = "category";
private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";

// products JSONArray
JSONArray events = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_latest);

    // Hashmap for ListView
    eventsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Loading products in Background Thread
    new LoadAllProducts().execute();

    // Get listview
//  ListView lv = getListView();



}

// Response from Edit Product Activity
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // if result code 100
    if (resultCode == 100) {
        // if result code 100 is received 
        // means user edited/deleted product
        // reload this screen again
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
 * */
class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Latest.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading Books. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * getting All products from url
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // products found
                // Getting Array of Products
                events = json.getJSONArray(TAG_BOOKS);

                // looping through All Products
                for (int i = events.length()-1; i > events.length()-4; i--) {
                    JSONObject c = events.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String pid = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                    String title = c.getString(TAG_TITLE);
                    String author = "Author :" +c.getString(TAG_AUTHOR);
                    String description = c.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION);
                    String price = "Price :" +c.getString(TAG_PRICE);
                    String discount = "Discount : " +c.getString(TAG_DISCOUNT);
                    String category = "Category :" +c.getString(TAG_CATEGORY);


                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_PID, pid);
                    map.put(TAG_TITLE, title);
                    map.put(TAG_AUTHOR, author);
                    map.put(TAG_DESCRIPTION, description);
                    map.put(TAG_PRICE, price);
                    map.put(TAG_DISCOUNT, discount);
                    map.put(TAG_CATEGORY, category);
                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    eventsList.add(map);
                }
            } 


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                /**
                 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                 * */
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        Latest.this, eventsList,
                        R.layout.list_item2, new String[] { TAG_PID, TAG_TITLE, TAG_AUTHOR, TAG_DESCRIPTION, TAG_PRICE, TAG_DISCOUNT, TAG_DESCRIPTION},
                        new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.title, R.id.author,R.id.description, R.id.price, R.id.discount,R.id.category });
                // updating listview
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });

    }

}
}
```

and this is the LogCat(error):

```
Buffer Error(1024): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
JSON Parser(1024): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
AndroidRuntime(1024): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
AndroidRuntime(1024): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing  doInBackground()
AndroidRuntime(1024):   at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
AndroidRuntime(1024):   at  java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
AndroidRuntime(1024):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
AndroidRuntime(1024):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
AndroidRuntime(1024):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
AndroidRuntime(1024):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
AndroidRuntime(1024):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
AndroidRuntime(1024): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
AndroidRuntime(1024):   at com.spyraa.bookstore.Latest$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(Latest.java:113)
AndroidRuntime(1024):   at com.spyraa.bookstore.Latest$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(Latest.java:1)
AndroidRuntime(1024):   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
AndroidRuntime(1024):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
AndroidRuntime(1024):   ... 3 more
```

this is the JSONParser class:

```
public class JSONParser {
    private static final String TAG = "JSONParser";

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

// function get json from url
// by making HTTP POST or GET method
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try{
        // check for request method
        if(method == "POST"){
            Log.d(TAG, "method=POST");
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            Log.d(TAG, "url=" + url);
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        }else if(method == "GET"){
            Log.d(TAG, "method=GET");
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            Log.d(TAG, "url=" + url);
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }           

        Log.d(TAG, "HTTP request done");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "UNSUPPORTED ENCODING: ", e);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "CLIENT PROTOCOL: ", e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "IO EXCEPTION: ", e);
    }

    try {
        Log.d(TAG, "Extract response");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "line=" + line);
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
        Log.d(TAG, "json=" + json);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Exception: ", e);
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        Log.d(TAG, "Parse JSON");
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "JSONException: ", e);
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
}
```

this is the recent logcat:

```
03-19 12:44:55.985: D/dalvikvm(919): GC_CONCURRENT freed 338K, 15% free 2791K/3268K, paused 111ms+119ms, total 437ms
03-19 12:45:10.246: D/dalvikvm(919): GC_CONCURRENT freed 373K, 16% free 2815K/3324K, paused 110ms+100ms, total 551ms
03-19 12:45:11.366: D/JSONParser(919): IO EXCEPTION: 
03-19 12:45:11.366: D/JSONParser(919): org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http:// refused
03-19 12:45:11.366: D/JSONParser(919):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:183)
03-19 12:45:11.366: D/JSONParser(919):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
03-19 12:45:11.366: D/JSONParser(919):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
03-19 12:45:11.366: D/JSONParser(919):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
03-19 12:45:11.366: D/JSONParser(919):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
03-19 12:45:11.366: D/JSONParser(919):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
03-19 12:45:11.366: D/JSONParser(919):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
03-19 12:45:11.366: D/JSONParser(919):  at com.spyraa.bookstore.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:66)
03-19 12:45:11.366: D/JSONParser(919):  at com.spyraa.bookstore.Latest$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(Latest.java:105)
03-19 12:45:11.366: D/JSONParser(919):  at com.spyraa.bookstore.Latest$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(Latest.java:1)
03-19 12:45:11.366: D/JSONParser(919):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
03-19 12:45:11.366: D/JSONParser(919):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
03-19 12:45:11.366: D/JSONParser(919):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
03-19 12:45:11.366: D/JSONParser(919):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
03-19 12:45:11.366: D/JSONParser(919):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
03-19 12:45:11.366: D/JSONParser(919): Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to http/1 (port 80): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
03-19 12:45:11.366: D/JSONParser(919):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:114)
03-19 12:45:11.366: D/JSONParser(919):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
03-19 12:45:11.366: D/JSONParser(919):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
03-19 12:45:11.366: D/JSONParser(919):  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
03-19 12:45:11.366: D/JSONParser(919):  at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
03-19 12:45:11.366: D/JSONParser(919):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
03-19 12:45:11.366: D/JSONParser(919):  ... 14 more
03-19 12:45:11.366: D/JSONParser(919): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
03-19 12:45:11.366: D/JSONParser(919):  at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
03-19 12:45:11.366: D/JSONParser(919):  at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:85)
03-19 12:45:11.366: D/JSONParser(919):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
03-19 12:45:11.366: D/JSONParser(919):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
03-19 12:45:11.366: D/JSONParser(919):  ... 19 more
03-19 12:45:11.499: D/JSONParser(919): Extract response
03-19 12:45:12.838: D/JSONParser(919): Exception: 
03-19 12:45:12.838: D/JSONParser(919): java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
03-19 12:45:12.838: D/JSONParser(919):  at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:64)
03-19 12:45:12.838: D/JSONParser(919):  at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:79)
03-19 12:45:12.838: D/JSONParser(919):  at com.spyraa.bookstore.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:83)
03-19 12:45:12.838: D/JSONParser(919):  at com.spyraa.bookstore.Latest$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(Latest.java:105)
03-19 12:45:12.838: D/JSONParser(919):  at com.spyraa.bookstore.Latest$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(Latest.java:1)
03-19 12:45:12.838: D/JSONParser(919):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
03-19 12:45:12.838: D/JSONParser(919):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
03-19 12:45:12.838: D/JSONParser(919):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
03-19 12:45:12.838: D/JSONParser(919):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
03-19 12:45:12.838: D/JSONParser(919):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
03-19 12:45:12.985: D/JSONParser(919): Parse JSON
03-19 12:45:31.570: D/JSONParser(919): JSONException: 
03-19 12:45:31.570: D/JSONParser(919): org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
03-19 12:45:31.570: D/JSONParser(919):  at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:450)
03-19 12:45:31.570: D/JSONParser(919):  at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:97)
03-19 12:45:31.570: D/JSONParser(919):  at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:154)
03-19 12:45:31.570: D/JSONParser(919):  at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
03-19 12:45:31.570: D/JSONParser(919):  at com.spyraa.bookstore.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:101)
03-19 12:45:31.570: D/JSONParser(919):  at com.spyraa.bookstore.Latest$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(Latest.java:105)
03-19 12:45:31.570: D/JSONParser(919):  at com.spyraa.bookstore.Latest$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(Latest.java:1)
03-19 12:45:31.570: D/JSONParser(919):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
03-19 12:45:31.570: D/JSONParser(919):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
03-19 12:45:31.570: D/JSONParser(919):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
03-19 12:45:31.570: D/JSONParser(919):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
03-19 12:45:31.570: D/JSONParser(919):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
03-19 12:45:32.365: D/dalvikvm(919): GC_CONCURRENT freed 412K, 17% free 2798K/3352K, paused 55ms+31ms, total 671ms
```

besides the above, most of the logcat consists these both:

```
03-19 12:45:44.466: I/Choreographer(919): Skipped 289 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-19 12:45:44.706: W/Trace(919): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
```

Comment: Please indicate the line where the exception is thrown.

Comment: inside this function:

[ protected String doInBackground(String... args) ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't provided line numbers, I can just guess.

> Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of

hints at an invalid JSON string. You should print the received JSON string to logcat for debugging.

**Update**:

The problem with `JSONParser` (what I have seen so far) is primarily that it catches exceptions, dumps some message and then *continues*. The consequence is that you usually have several messages and don't know really where it failed initially.

This is why you must add trace statements into `makeHttpRequest()` to see where it fails. Another (additional) approach would be to remove all try/catch statements and let the exception propagate outside. Then you will have a stack trace where the first failure is and can see what the real cause of your problem is.

But even with that, proper tracing and debugging logs are essential.

Comment: is this what you meant?

    Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

Comment: @A.K.C.F.L Yes, with that you can see what the http request delivers. Although, it might be nothing is shown, because of "character 0". Which JSONParser are you using, btw?

Comment: i already have that code and yes it doesn't help. and i'm not sure which one JSONParser i'm using. i have very less knowledge about it, and my JSONParser is almost the same as in this page - 
(http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/)

Comment: @A.K.C.F.L I have seen various versions of this code and all are more or less buggy. But you have the code and can put debug statements into it, to trace where it fails.

Comment: do you have any other option than this JSONParser which is not buggy?

Comment: @A.K.C.F.L No, I haven't done this myself. Please see updated answer.

Comment: i did as u mentioned, adding few log traces in the JSONParser class and also the class i posted here. but there are no errors for the newly added codes and none from the JSONParser class. the previous errors are still the same.

Comment: @A.K.C.F.L You should see from the trace logs, if every statement in your `makeHttpRequest()` is run or if there's a jump somewhere. Also, if you still see the error messages, this means the `try/catch`s are still there. Since I don't know your concrete JSONParser implementation, I cannot be of more help here, sorry.

Comment: i really need to get this working by end of this week. if you don't mind, do you want to see my JSONParser class? please do help.

Comment: @A.K.C.F.L I added some debug logs to your JSONParser. Look if it compiles and post the new logcat output, when your done.

Comment: thank you for helping in changing my code. and i have updated the question with the logcat.

Comment: @A.K.C.F.L Right the first exception says it already, "Connection to `http://w.x.y.z` refused". This means, your web server is not running at the given server or the firewall blocks the access. Therefore the request cannot be sent and you never receive any response.

Comment: oh, but when i opened the (http://) using the browser, it does show the results. how come?

Comment: @A.K.C.F.L I don't know. If you run this on an emulator, maybe this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/4905367/1741542 helps. BTW, in the new logcat output, I miss two entries: `method=GET` and `url=...`. Did you cut these out?

Comment: no i didn't cut out, just maybe i forgot to select it from the long list of the output. sorry. 

03-19 14:07:32.976: D/JSONParser(1501): method=GET
03-19 14:07:32.976: D/JSONParser(1501): url=http://xxx?

Comment: @A.K.C.F.L I just wanted to know, if the log worked properly. You need the url to see, that it is setup correctly. Also, if the `url=` log were not there, the exception would have occurred in `new DefaultHttpClient()`, which would be really strange.

Comment: ok. actually, i really don't know how to put this to words but my system is working. i changed the (Http:) which it was not working when i put the address to the browser and that's the one which is working for my system. thank you so much. you helped so so much. thanks for your help again. :)

Comment: I'm glad you can keep the deadline. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like mishandled JSON data.  Are you sure of the structure of the JSON you're getting?  A sample of that might help.

Comment: I'm not sure of the structure, but i followed the logic of the flow. tried viewing few samples in Google but nothing seem right.