# whitelisting a domain in ionic app

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am going through the ionic tutorial present in

```
http://ccoenraets.github.io/ionic-tutorial/build-ionic-project.html
```

and ran the app on browser

```
ionic serve
```

and in android using

```
ionic emulate android
```

When I run the app as instructed in tutorial, it works well on my chrome browser but when I try to run on emulator, I dont see any data, its just empty screens with menus. I suspect its the problem with whilelist and added

```
  <allow-navigation href="*" />
```

to my /config.xml file but it still doesn't work, My current config.xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<widget id="com.ionicframework.conference472350" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
  <name>conference</name>
  <description>
        An Ionic Framework and Cordova project.
    </description>
  <author email="hi@ionicframework" href="http://ionicframework.com/">
      Ionic Framework Team
    </author>
  <content src="index.html"/>
  <access origin="*" />
  <allow-intent href="*" />
  <allow-navigation href="*" />
  <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16"/>
  <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000"/>
  <feature name="StatusBar">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVStatusBar" onload="true"/>
  </feature>
  <platform name="android">
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" density="ldpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" density="mdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" density="hdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" density="xhdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxhdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" density="land-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" density="land-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" density="land-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xxxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxxhdpi"/>
  </platform>
</widget>
```

I am debugging the app in chrome devtools and this is the error I get in console for the app

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

[image]

Comment: Have you added the `meta` tag to your **index.html** file? If not, then add this line of code: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">`

Comment: I added this meta tag but I still have 1 error of ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interestingly enough, I had the same issue while developing my app.

Have you installed the plugin correctly? You didn't mention if you did.

You need to install the [cordova whitelist plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist) first. I did this via [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-whitelist).

I also added all access to resources in my config.xml:

```
  <access origin="*" />
  <allow-intent href="*" />
  <allow-navigation href="*" />
```

Though, that is not recommended. Rather, allow access to the resources you need for the app.

Comment: gives the error on debug console of my app  No Content-Security-Policy meta tag found. Please add one when using the cordova-plugin-whitelist plugin.plugins/cordova-plugin-whitelist/whitelist.js:23 (anonymous function)

Comment: Can you post the full content of your new config.xml? If you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30212306/no-content-security-policy-meta-tag-found-error-in-my-phonegap-application, it should have worked.

Comment: added full content. I didnt see anyone writing where to add those tags in config.xml. Is that the problem

Comment: I added meta tag and managed to get rid of few errors but I still have 1 error.

Comment: @raju - the error you seem to have now is not with whitelisting. It seems that the firewall could be blocking your app on the phone. Try and add a rule to allow connections to your local machine on port 5000. The app is just being refused rights to connect.

Comment: I got it working after cvhanging localhost to 10.0.2.2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4905315/error-connection-refused