# Issue with ionic android signed apk build

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am facing an issue with ionic android signed apk. My code is working absolutely fine on app-debug.apk but it isn't showing data for app-release.apk. Release apk is getting installed properly but it isn't showing data. I suspected that it could be an issue of ssl certificate on APIs. I bought ssl and put, however issue still persist. Any lead would be appreciated. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Depending on the version of ionic, I think that if you call external webservices, you should whitelist them
see : https://stackoverflow.com/a/30726493/2745931

Answer (score 0):

Add this line into **config.xml** just after  `<platform name="android">` line .Hope it will work

```
<edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application">
            <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />
        </edit-config>
```

Answer (score 0):

if your API data is not being shown kindly check your url
it must be https
if it is
http://example.org
then data will not be shown on mobile device or emulator change it to
https://example.org